# New SQL Server Report Data Source Type

Tags: 2013, reporting-services, business-intelligence, powerview

I am trying to create a Report Data Source to connect a traditional relational database for reporting. The connection is successful but when I try to create a Power View report, it gives me an error

```
"The current action cannot be completed. The data extension type for data source 'http://myserver/Shared Documents/AdventureWorksDW.rsds' is not valid for this operation."
```

My query is, whether it is possible to create a power view erport connecting to a relational database rather than an analysis server database? if yes, what mistake am I making?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a tabular data model or Multi-dimensional model/Cube [SQL 2012 CTP Edition only] from your relational database and deploy it to an analysis server instance.

As clearly mentioned in [technet documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213579.aspx)

> Power View is a thin web client that launches right in the browser
>   from a data model in SharePoint Server 2010. The model can be a
>   PowerPivot model workbook or a tabular model running on a SQL Server
>   2012 Analysis Services (SSAS) server.

Comment: Is there any documentation or steps on how to create a tabular data model or Multi-dimensional model/Cube from a relational database?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/video/building-the-perfect-bi-semantic-tabular-models-for-power-view.aspx