# Power View in SharePoint Server - The data extension type for a data source is not valid

Tags: sharepoint-server, powerview

All of a sudden I am getting following error when trying to create Power View report using shared report data source (no error testing the connection):

> The current action cannot be completed. The data extension type for a
>   data source `http://dev.com/Shared Ducuments/Sales.rsds` is not valid
>   for this operation

I already have a data source (I had created it after creating my site collection a week ago) and when I use this source to create Power View report then there is no error but I am getting above error when I create another similar data source and use it to create a Power View report.

Please help me to resolve the error.

Comment: I am struggling with the error. I have a multidimensional cube as opposed the error mentioned in this post: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/75698/new-sql-server-report-data-source-type

Comment: I am going nuts! I had selected 'Analysis Services' instead of 'Microsoft BI Semantic Model for Power View'